# MVC Area error on ActionExecutingContext Filter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i'm getting a `non static method requires a target` error on my `ActionExecutingContext Filter`, this filter will search some data on the DB and provide it to the called controller via `ViewBag of the filterContext`, this is the code:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    using (var db = new Entities())
    {
        var redirect = MvcApplication.reqContext;
        var seos     = db.SEO.Where(x => x.ID == redirect.seoId).ToList();
        var desconto = db.QueroDesconto.First();

        //Recupera cookie banner home
        filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.BannerHome = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["BannerHome"] != null ? int.Parse(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["BannerHome"].Value) : 0;

        filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.objEstados    = objEstados;
        filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.Desconto      = desconto;

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

The thing is, it only happens when i'm accessing a MVC Area and it never happened when i'm debugging

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was in my DB search where i was receiving a null value in my `redirect var`.

This var was only been populated at my root project in my route handler controller that is executed every time i 'ask' for a page and since my Area wasn't executing this controller i would always get the null value.

Now, the only working in debug thing was happening because every time i would debug it, by default, i would start at the root project and thus with a null value